# gdb proceed execution until new frame on the call stack

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, clang

Is there a way to proceed execution in gdb until a function is called and then pause inside that function? It is a pain to use `n` and `s` for the code I am working with. I would much prefer a `nextFrame` and `fin`, assuming a `nextFrame` existed which took me into a new function. It would be extra cool if `nextFrame` could tell me when we only unwind the stack from the current scope, i.e. we do not make another function call, and then it could pause at the last line of the current scope.

Basically, I want to view my codebase from a callstack perspective and not from a line by line perspective.

P.S. Assuming such a facility exists, I would imagine it being problematic to use with `boost`. Eg. if I have a line like  `boost::shared_ptr<MyType> a = foo();` then it will pause first inside `boost` code, before it pauses inside `foo()`. This is a problem because I am not interested in the boost code and only want to see what is inside `foo`.

P.S. I also have clang. I wonder if this is possible in clang.

Comment: You can script GDB to either: set breakpoints on all function (symbols) if you have debugging information, or to automatically step for you and break on `call` and `ret` instructions & equivalents. Multiple implementations of these approaches exist out there..

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Thanks, this sounds interesting

Answer (score 0):

Use `b function_name` to apply the break point inside a function.
Your program in execution will pause at the entry of that function.
Alternatively You can also use
`b filename:line_number` to pause the execution of your program at the specific line in a file.

Comment: This is not a better alternative to next and step